# How to create setup application for xampp

Tags: c#, php

I am having one project and i run this project using xampp. I need to start xampp and start mysql and apache and copy project folder to htdocs and run. Now i need to run the program with single click.is it possible?

Comment: did you try : https://www.wampserver.com/en/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me that you want to run your php-application as a type of standalone-application.

You can solve your problem for sure by writing a [windows batch script](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Batch_Scripting).
Or you can try to pack your php-application as an executable file with [php-desktop](https://github.com/cztomczak/phpdesktop/).